# How do I create a Multi-Section Quiz in Moodle 3.3.1?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am using **Moodle** version **3.3.1** on a Xampp apache server with MySql database. I am interested in making a multiple choice quiz that has the following features:

- Has multiple sections (e.g. Quiz on Physics has sections Thermodynamics, Electromagnetism, Relativity etc.)
- Each section must be passed 70% or greater to pass the entire quiz.
- Feedback must be given on whether you pass a section or not and the grade/score for each section
- Feedback must be given on whether you passed the entire quiz.

I understand that this functionality may not be innately possible with moodle. I cannot use multiple quizzes for each section as I am creating a quiz based on a quiz that has been in use for decades and has an already established set of rules(particularly time for the quiz) that cannot be changed by the stakeholders easily.

Are there any plugins that can provide that functionality(I have looked with no luck)?

If that isn't possible can anyone **point me in the right direction** to create a plugin or edit Moodle PHP code to create this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Building_Quiz 
Never ignore the official documentation for Moodle

Also

https://www.moodleworld.com/moodle-tips-by-moodlefairy-add-sections-and-conditional-questions-to-your-quiz/

Comment: Thanks you for your prompt feedback. Unfortunately neither of those links help with the second and third features outlined in the question.

Comment: So, I found a plugin that does provide some of the features but not all, but I am posting for anyone else who is interested. https://github.com/jamiepratt/moodle-mod_quiz_accessrule_gradebycategory